# Search a Map for multiple keys in parallel

Tags: java, dictionary, parallel-processing

Given a `Map<String, Collection<String>>` up to 1M items. I know what to query that Map for 5K keys, of which I'm unsure whether they are in the map or not.

Currently, I'm using a TreeMap and search for each item, one by one. Which seems sub-optimal. Is there an, already, implemented way to query a Map for X keys?

The result of the search should be a subset of items, which are found in the Map, for further querying - ordering is irrelevant.

I was hoping to use `stream`, but, apparently, that's only for Collections.

Note: the number are impressions, from what I've seen in the map, probably not the upper limit...

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way than querying your map for each element:

```
List<V> vs = keysToSearch.stream()
                         .map(k -> map.get(k))
                         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You can also try using a `parallelStream` if your data structures work in a concurrent environment.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't do `parallelStream`? (hmm, and there is the parallelStream)... Still not really an upside over `foreach`

Comment: I just added it as a possibility

Answer (score 1):

assuming memory is not a problem for you. here is one way of doing it.

by using `retainAll`

```
Set<String> mapKeys = new HashSet<String>(myMap.keySet());

mapKeys.retainAll(my5kKeys);  //<--- all keys that match the my5kKeys...
```

Comment: I'm afraid memory is an issue, because the code will be executed by between 1 - 20 threads

Comment: this is the fastest way of doing it. so if your Map is 1M+ and between 20 threads. it means that you need space for 20M strings... well you can do the math. anyways. u may just give it a try. it might not be as bad as it seems

Comment: I'll give it a shot... The approach has its upsides, but does not return a map, but a set instead

Answer (score 1):

If you have M items in your map, and K keys you are searching for, then your best-case efficiency is O(min(M, K)).  If M is very large, the best you can do is to check each K (perhaps in parallel, but you must do each).

*If* it were the case that M turned out to be much smaller than K, then you could do better by only checking through all M values to see if they existed in K.  In any event, you want to check the smaller set's values against the larger.

Comment: Like you `O` comments... The ratio will start like I stated, and will probably only grow towards a bigger M

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way then to create a loop and search for all the keys individually.
A method like `retainAll` is just a wrapper around such a loop written by somebody else.

However, the important thing is to use a `HashMap` instead of a `TreeMap`. Hashmaps `contains` is O(1) while `Treemap` takes O(log(n)).

If you need the sorted collection for something else, you could put the data in both a `TreeMap` and a `HashMap`.

Comment: Crap, you're right... I used TreeMap because of the `log(n)`, but I think my reasoning was backwards (it was there though :p). But, please explain, if in TreeMap the ordering is based on `compareTo()`, HashMap has none, why then would HashMap be faster, since you know how to search for a value in TreeMap, you don't for HashMap. So, logically, the O(1) and O(log(n)) is insert time, whereas search time must be faster for TreeMap

Comment: HashMap is O(1) for insert and O(1) for contains. Treemap is O(log(n) for insert and O(log(n)) for contains. If you're never interested in sorted values `HashMap` is simply faster.

Comment: I don't think I can fit a better explanation of HashMap in this comment then you can find on the web. But I'll try to answer your question anyway: `HashMap` uses the `hashCode` function on the String key you're providing. Internally it has an array of LinkedLists and it uses that hashCode to instantly know in what LinkedList to look. If the HashMap is properly balanced (and it is by default) that list will be reasonably short (<1 on average) and lookup in a very short LinkedList is also very fast.